# How to increase _PAGESIZE_ in _chkstk in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, stack, stack-overflow

As we know the Visual C++ compiler inserts a function called `_chkstk()`.

In this function we can find that our page size is 4KB:

```
; size of a page of memory

_PAGESIZE_      equ     1000h
```

The question is how to correctly increase this size?

Comment: Uh the page size is a property of the x86 CPU...

Comment: If you're concerned about how often _chkstk() gets called, it's possible to reduce stack probes with the [/Gs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9598wk25.aspx) compiler option and the #pragma [check_stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybwsy5f9.aspx) directive. This is something I'd consider only if I was very concerned about my stack performance characteristics and convinced I could do better by hand, or if I was trying to build without the CRT for, say, a device driver.